# Is there a generic way to display progress bar over Views in Android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, progress-bar

I have seen numerous posts on how to display progress bar while the data loads in the background. All suggestions requires we manually place a ProgressBar in the layout xml and then use an `AsyncTask` to show and hide the ProgressBar and the View in question.

However, I would like to make a generic class which creates the ProgressBar programmatically at runtime and place it exactly over the view in question and maybe also slightly shade or blur the view while the ProgressBar is displayed. Had this been a Swing application I would have painted my progress bar on the ["glass pane"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) of the view after slightly shading it with gray. In that case since the progress bar is the child of the same pseudo parent hence I could easily position that as centred.

In Android UI toolkit I am not aware of any such "glass panes". How do I achieve this effect?

Comment: This doesn't exist. The closes analog is to [set progress from an Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setProgress(int)), which displays under the actionbar. You do need to [request this feature](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#requestWindowFeature(int)).

Answer (score 0):

Make a BaseActivity that you derive all your Activities from (same goes for Fragments).

Give it something like

```
protected void showLoading(){

  ViewGroup content = findViewById(...); 
  content.setVisibility(Visibility.GONE); 

  ViewGroup root = findViewById(...); 
  root.addView(new ProgressBar()); 

}
```

Gotta make sure all your layouts have a ViewGroup for root and one for content, which otherwise might not be necessary and bloat layouts, but thats how I do it and it works fine. 
Above is pseudocode of course, but you get the idea.

There's also this libary: http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/progressfragment/, but I don't think it's necessary to import a library for that task.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have to create this functionality. I always do this by creating a class from a framelayout and then place my imageview inside with my progressbar ontop. I then create an interface I use as a callback so that when said process is complete and the data is finished being processed I get my callback and I hide the progressbar. I use a framelayout because its the easiest view to use to "stack" views ontop of one another by simply placing them inside the FrameLayout. You may also need to place views inside the frame inside of a relativelayout with the width and height set to match parent so you can set the layout_centerInParent to true on your progressbar so it sits nicely inside your compound view.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure I get the question right, because it seems easier to me than it might be. But anyway:

To instantiate programmatically a progress bar, you need to do the following in your activity:

```
    ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(this);
    ((ViewGroup) this.findViewById(R.id.view_that_will_contain_progressbar)).addView(pb);
```

This will add the view to the ViewGroup `view_that_will_contain_progressbar`. This ViewGroup should be a `FrameLayout` if you want to overlay over other information.

*Tip*: if you want to customize your ProgressBar, you can declare it in a layout file, and do the following to instantiate and attach the PB (still in your activity/fragment) :

`this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.progressbar,parent);`

with parent refering to the parent you want to attach it to.